# Move files using shortcut keys in Forklift for Mac

Tags: macos, keyboard, finder

Does anyone know here how to move files using just shortcut keys in Forklift for Mac? I just don't like to click File > Move to, to move files/folders from one tab to another. I think there's a short cut key or I think I can set a shortcut key, but I just don't know how to do it in Forklift. It's not even in their FAQs and I cannot find any post online regarding Forklift shortcut keys.

I just want to select files and copy/move from one tab to another fast, without pointing my mouse to the move to link under File in the top menu.

I hope somebody here is familiar with Forklift and would share some tips of how to move files fast from one tab to another. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a keyboard shortcut for the Move To command in the Forklift preferences. I tested using Command-Shift-M, which is unused in the default Forklift shortcuts. With that configured, any files/folders selected in the active browsing pane will be moved to the location in the other browsing pane.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

- <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between left and right pane
- Cursor keys to move up and down within a pane
- <kbd>Cmd-C</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd-V</kbd> to copy/paste files and folders

Comment: Thanks but it didn't move any files. It just copied it from one pane to another. Haha :D